# Compress image file to specified size

Tags: android

I have a requirement to make sure that all pictures my users take from `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` Intent in my app are under 4 MB due to server restrictions.  What would be the best way to go about doing this?  The files are JPEG if that matters.

So far I'm using a brute force method below but this doesn't work. **(Edit: It works now with suggestions given below, but takes a while)**  I'm wondering if there is some more efficient method, perhaps using BitmapFactory.Options.inJustDecodeBounds, that could maybe map pixel count to number of bytes so I wouldn't need so many IO operations.

```
private final int MAX_IMAGE_SIZE = 4194304;

private void shrinkImageFile(File file) throws IOException
{
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
    int quality = 90;

    while (file.length() > MAX_IMAGE_SIZE )
    {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, out);
        quality -= 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a better way than brute force, but you could clean up your current approach. Initialize the `Bitmap` and `FileoutputStream` outside your loop, and decrease your compression quality each iteration rather than recreating the `Bitmap` object.

Comment: I've edited it, it works now but takes a while.  Also, can't initialize the stream outside the loop because that truncates the file.

Comment: One approach would be to write the compressed data into a memory buffer rather than a file - then check the amount of the consumed memory.  Once you've got the right size, you can just dump the memory buffer into a file once.  This will be a lot faster.

Comment: (continued)   Have a look at class `MemoryFile` - it may be what you need to use here.

Comment: I'm using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of a `FileOutputStream` now but it doesn't seem to make it much quicker.